# PostgreSQL set PGDATA variable

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3, drbd

Server: Ubuntu server 14 lts + PostgreSQL 9.2
I want create cluster database using drbd, but i can't set PGDATA without cluster initialization. I just need say pgsql use data from drbd disk. How i can do it?

Example 1:

```
mkdir /cluster/var/lib/pgsql -p
chown postgres:postgres /cluster/var/lib/pgsql -R
cp -R /var/lib/pgsql /cluster/var/lib/pgsql

edit /etc/init.d/postgresql :
 PGDATA=/cluster/var/lib/pgsql/data
...
PGLOG=/cluster/var/lib/pgsql/pgstartup.log

/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

in postgresql 8.3 it works, but in 9.2 i can't change pgdata in /etc/init.d/postgresql, i need find another file and set pgdata, but, surprise, it's do nothing.

Example 2:
PGDATA - Specifies the directory where the database cluster is to be stored; can be overridden using the -D option.

Ok, let's start:
--pgdata=directory
yeah, it's works! but now we have postgresql-xc and error like "postgresql don't know this user - postgresql".
drbd start replicate data from cluster, but postgresql start it too.

UPD 1:

```
root: initdb --pgdata=/home/username/dir
~initdb not install~bla-bla-bla~use apt-get install postgres-xc
```

UPD2:

```
$: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb --pgdata=/whateveryouwant

#now you can run postgresql only one way:

$: /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres -D /see_up

#then:

LOG:  database system was shut down at 2014-09-26 15:56:33 YEKT   
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections    
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started

#aaaaaaaaaaand...nothing. just empty console, ^C stopping postgres    
#another SSH connect:

$: ps-ela

S  1000  5995  5217  0  80   0 - 62202 poll_s pts/0    00:00:00 postgres    
1 S  1000  5997  5995  0  80   0 - 62202 poll_s ?        00:00:00 postgres    
1 S  1000  5998  5995  0  80   0 - 62202 poll_s ?        00:00:00 postgres    
1 S  1000  5999  5995  0  80   0 - 62202 poll_s ?        00:00:00 postgres    
1 S  1000  6000  5995  0  80   0 - 62415 poll_s ?        00:00:00 postgres    
1 S  1000  6001  5995  0  80   0 - 26121 poll_s ?        00:00:00 postgres

#is it ok? because...

$: /etc/init.d/postgresql status    
9.3/main (port 5432): down
```

Comment: "*i can't set PGDATA without cluster initialization*" that does not make sense. `PGDATA` is an **environment** variable. It doesn't require anything in order to be set. Just define it in your `.profile` or through a `set` command.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-initdb.html <= in psql 9.2 you can set pgdata only use initdb, after that pgsql will controling by postgresql-xc. if you want set pgdata use text editor you get nothing...

Comment: Again: PGDATA is an ***environment*** variable. Unless you don't mean `PGDATA` but the actual *data directory*. Those are two different things (the variable `PGDATA` usually _points_ to the data directory that should be used by Postgres). Also: if you are using Postgres-XC you should have mentioned that from the beginning. Postgres-XC and PostgreSQL are two different things.

Comment: i'am add example...and yeah, i understood what is pgdata variable. But it's not work for me. When i use --pgdata=directory i can't take any data from psql

Comment: **Sharing a PostgreSQL data directory between two running PostgreSQL instances using a file system mounted on drbd is guaranteed to cause severe data corruption**. This is true even if it's a cluster file system, because PostgreSQL its self requires that only one PostgreSQL instance *ever* access the data directory at a time. Do not do this. If you attempt it you will completely destroy your database.

Comment: (You also keep on mentioning postgres-xc. Which is it, PostgreSQL, or postgres-xc? They're not the same thing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the below in your ~/.bashrc file.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/<PostgresVersionNumber>/bin
export PATH
export PGDATA="$HOME/<FolderNameForPostgresDatabases>"
```

Replace 'PostgresVersionNumber' with your installed Postgres version number. 
Replace 'FolderNameForPostgresDatabases' with the name of the folder you want your postgres databases to reside. Make sure the folder is created

From a terminal, you have to navigate to ~/FolderNameForPostgresDatabases,
then run:

```
initdb
```

Do that before trying to run:

```
pg_ctl start
```

Answer (score 6):

With Ubuntu, to use a specific data directory for a PostgreSQL instance, you just need to do:

```
# pg_createcluster --datadir=/path/to/the/directory 9.3 nameofcluster
```

You don't need or want to fiddle with `$PGDATA` anywhere. See [pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) manpage.

If using `drdb` to replicate the data directory in a cluster, keep in mind that the term `cluster` 
in PostgreSQL parlance has a different signification: it's always a cluster of databases, which means all the databases served by a specific PostgreSQL instance with its unique data directory. This differs from a `drdb cluster` which is a cluster of machines.

The data directory of a PostgreSQL cluster cannot be shared at all, in the sense that only one specific instance of PostgreSQL running on a single machine may write into it, otherwise corruption will ensue.

If `drdb` is configured to conform with this requirement, it's OK to use it, otherwise not.
You may also question why using `drdb` in the first place when PostgreSQL has [built-in replication options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html)  since version 8.3 that are more specialized and better suited to a database than pure disk replication.